# Cannot change style with :nth-of-type(n)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem with the pseudo class `:nth-of-type(n)`.

I need to change the background-color of `.aside_box_content` 1,2,3,4...

I tried to use the pseudo class when divs are not nested in other divs and it works, so there's an error somewhere.

```css
.aside_box_content {
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aside_box_content:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div id="aside_caption">INFO</div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">YOUTUBE</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">TWITTER</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">FACEBOOK</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">CALENDAR</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content">

    </div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">TIME</div>
  </div>

</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child` instead of `:nth-of-type`

```css
 .aside_box_content {
     height: 130px;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .aside_box:nth-child(3) .aside_box_content {
     background-color: purple;
 }
```

```html
<aside>
    <div id="aside_caption">INFO</div>
    <!-- NEW BOX -->
    <div class="aside_box">
        <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
        <div class="footer_of_box_aside">YOUTUBE</div>
    </div>
    <!-- NEW BOX -->
    <div class="aside_box">
        <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
        <div class="footer_of_box_aside">TWITTER</div>
    </div>
    <!-- NEW BOX -->
    <div class="aside_box">
        <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
        <div class="footer_of_box_aside">FACEBOOK</div>
    </div>
    <!-- NEW BOX -->
    <div class="aside_box">
        <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
        <div class="footer_of_box_aside">CALENDAR</div>
    </div>
    <!-- NEW BOX -->
    <div class="aside_box">
        <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
        <div class="footer_of_box_aside">TIME</div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: `nth-child` doesn't target classes or ids either. It selects the nth-child element and the element could be any type of element, could have any class etc. The class attached to the `:nth-child` (or `:nth-of-type`) for that matter is only a combinator which ***also*** have to be matched but the class is not the primary.

Comment: @ExDirty "nth-of-type is used to target tags, not classes or ids." This is incorrect, nth-of-type works just fine with classes. http://jsfiddle.net/gs700kv4/

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! Edited the answer. @apaul34208 Although I know it works but thought of the convention it is used for.

Comment: As mentioned under the other answer in response to apaul, throw in a classless p and [nth-of-type stops working as you might expect](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/gs700kv4/4). Posting this comment here since this answer is now accepted and pinned up top.

Comment: @BoltClock "nth-of-type is used to target tags, not classes or ids." so this statement is partially or completely correct?

Comment: Pedantically, a selector targets *elements* based on different criteria such as class, id and tagname. nth-of-type doesn't care what class or id the element has, only its tagname, and even then you can target elements of different types by nth of type if you don't specify a type selector, e.g. *:nth-of-type(2n) rather than p:nth-of-type(2n).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `nth-of-type` elements need to be in the same parent as direct children of that parent. Change your CSS to target the `.aside-box` instead. And wrap all your `.aside-box` divs in a single parent.

```css
 .aside_box_content {
   height: 130px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .aside_box:nth-of-type(3) .aside_box_content {
   background-color: purple;
 }
```

```html
<aside>
  <div id="aside_caption">INFO</div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box_wrapper">
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">YOUTUBE</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">TWITTER</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">FACEBOOK</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">CALENDAR</div>
  </div>
  <!-- NEW BOX -->
  <div class="aside_box">
    <div class="aside_box_content"></div>
    <div class="footer_of_box_aside">TIME</div>
  </div>
  </div><!-- .aside_box_wrapper -->
</aside>
```

Comment: Just wanted to know if we can use `:nth-of-type` with classes?

Comment: @ManojKumar Nope. That's why you need to wrap the elements that you want to target in a parent div. The person who edited my answer removed that.

Comment: @disinfor The markup in the question already had a wrapping parent. I edited your answer because your selector was slightly off, but your reasoning was correct.

Comment: @apaul34208 ahh..the `aside`. All of the resources I've found (and experience), `nth-of-type` disregards class and selects elements. If you take your fiddle from above http://jsfiddle.net/gs700kv4/1/, add another `<p>` tag as the second without a class. It does something I didn't expect.

Comment: Hmm that's odd, I see what your saying. [The docs say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type): "The :nth-of-type CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings **with the same element name before it in the document tree**, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element." It looks like you can use classes as long as they are sequential.

Comment: @apaul34208 That's awesome information to have! Thanks for posting that.